# "Walk in" or "Walk into"? How to decide whether to use "in" or "into"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage, prepositional-phrases

"You can't just walk in/into the class without permission". What is the word to go by in this statement?

Comment: This questions needs relocated to another forum, right? And then that other forum would probably flag it as duplicate.

Comment: Well, if you are walking along and not looking ahead of you, you might walk *into* a parking meter, but I doubt that you could walk *in* one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends...

- Walking *in* class **includes** the possibility of simply walking about
  the classroom.
- Walking in-*to* class **excludes**  the above (at least) and is more
  specific.